# ReactJS Add local path

Tags: reactjs, stormpath, express-stormpath

I am just starting with ReactJS and trying to integrate with Stormpath for user login. They provide default behaviors for /register and /login path.

I want ReactJS to redirect to those local links for now rather than creating new routes and components. How can this be achieved.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I also work at Stormpath and just a few days ago I released the [Stormpath React SDK](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-react). With this you'll be able to integrate Stormpath into your React application with very little effort.

To get started checkout our [example application](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-express-react-example) or read the [blog post](https://stormpath.com/blog/build-a-react-app-with-user-authentication/) I wrote for it.

And if you have any questions, feel free to hit me up at `robin [at] stormpath [dot] com`.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I work at [Stormpath](https://stormpath.com).  We're recommending that you try to use our [express-stormpath](https://github.com/stormpath/express-stormpath) module.  But we do have some issues that we're working on fixing.

It is not yet possible to disable the default HTML views, but still retain the JSON API. We will be fixing this in a future release. This creates a problem for React Flux applications that want to use the /login route in their browser application, but not use our default HTML views.

To work around the problem, you can change the uri of the route to a different URL than /login. For example:

```
app.use(stormpath.init(app, {
  website: true,
  web: {
     login: {
      uri: '/api/login'
    }
  }
}));
```

Your browser code will need to make it’s login POST to /api/login

Can you give this a try and let me know if is helps?  Thanks!